# "ORDER BY" Command Assistance in SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi guys I am trying to display the name, salary and commission for all employees who earn commissions and sorting the data in descending order of salary and commissions.

I have written the following code but I dont think its right. Does anyone know if I have sorted it in **descending order of salary AND commissions?**

```
SELECT  ENAME, SAL, COMM
FROM    emp
WHERE   COMM IS NOT null
ORDER   BY SAL,COMM DESC;
```

**Thanks a lot guys.**

-Jay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need to do `ORDER   BY SAL DESC,COMM DESC;`

The `DESC` only applies to the immediately preceding expression. Not **all** of the preceding expressions, which means in your original query `SAL` will still be sorted ascending (the default when no sort order is explicitly specified).

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out with Sql.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 ORDER BY SAL DESC, COMM DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from employees order by salary desc,commission desc
```

[image: query results]

**EDITED**

you will be more clear with @Martin Smith answer i checked just now.

Comment: Thanks Rahul bhai ! Very illustrative answer

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the ROW_NUMBER() feature.

Check this out:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66512/

This is one step ahead for such requirements.

Hope this helps.